# How to take union to obtain closed set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> I want to write $[a,\infty)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ as a union of intervals with rational boundarypoints.

Since $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to $a$. However $$\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_n,n]=(a,\infty).$$
How do I obtain the closed interval $[a,\infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is not rational, you simply can't.

Suppose $a$ is irrational, and that $\cup_{i \in I} [a_i, b_i] = [a, \infty)$, as you desire. Then since $a$ is in the set on the right, $a$ must be in the union on the left, which means that for some $i \in I$, $a \in [a_i, b_i]$, i.e. $a_i \leq a \leq b_i$. If $a_i$ and $b_i$ are rational, then $a_i < a < b_i$, so there is some number $x$ with $a_i < x < a$ (for example, let $x$ be the average of $a$ and $a_i$). This $x$ is also in $[a_i, b_i]$, so it is in the aforementioned union, but it is not in $[a, \infty)$, since $x < a$. This is a contradiction, all because $a$ was not rational.

In essence, in order to include $a$ in the union, you have to have an interval that includes $a$. But if $a$ is irrational and the interval endpoints are rational, you contain too many points besides $a$.

Comment: If I want to write $(a,\infty)$ as a union using $(a_n)_{n}$. How would I do that? Because I don't know beforehand that $a_n<n$

Comment: First make sure $(a_n)$ is monotonic decreasing. That's important for how you want to use it. Then start the sequence some $n$ such that $a \geq a_n$.

Comment: Can I always find a monotonic decreasing $(a_n)$?

Comment: Sure. How exactly depends on how much you're allowed to  use about the reals. You could use something like the decimal expansion of $a$ and round up at each finite truncation of it.